# Cross Validation and perfcurv in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cross-validation, auc

I am trying to use perfcurv in a cross validation code. However at some point all the members of the test dataset are of the same class (0). My problem is a binary classification problem. Therefore the following error occurs:

> Error using perfcurve (line 368) Less than two classes are found in
>   the array of true class labels.
>
> Error in loadsurfperframe_GIE_leave_one_out (line 669)
>       [x,y,t,AUC(i),OPTROCPT,SUBY,SUBYNAMES] = perfcurve(test_classes,ytest,1);

What should I do to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `perfcurve()` computes the [Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) curve, which shows the trade-off between *Sensitivity* and *1-Specificity* for binary classification problem, i.e. which threshold value is more optimal. If you only have 0-samples is impossible to determine where to place the threshold.

[image]

Besides, the specificity is defined as `SEN = TP/T = TP/(TP+FN)`. If we consider negative samples as `0` and positive samples as `1`, your data does not have any positive samples. Thus, `TP = 0` implies that the value is always `SEN=0` independently of the threshold value.

Answer (score 2):

You should always provide samples of both classes in your ground truth data. Otherwise purfcurve would not work and you can't use this function.

You can't say what is precision and recall when you don't have two classes in your true data, So it's not logical at all. Just try to avoid the cases that all of your true data are from the same class.